# How do I only print a string with letters

Tags: python

How do I only print a string with letters? My attempt is below:

```
f=open("couple1.txt","r")
couple1=f.read()
print(couple1)
judgesscore1=int(input("Enter score"))
judgesscore2=int(input("Enter score"))
judgesscore3=int(input("Enter score"))
judgesscore4=int(input("Enter score"))
judgesscore5=int(input("Enter score"))
list=[judgesscore1,judgesscore2,judgesscore3,judgesscore4,judgesscore5]
maxscore=max(list)
minscore=min(list)
avgc1=(((judgesscore1+judgesscore2+judgesscore3+judgesscore4+judgesscore5)-maxscore)-minscore)
f=open("couple1.txt","a")
f.write(str(avgc1)+",")
f.close()
```

Comment: 1. No formatting done | 
2. No explanation | 
3. Hurt my eyes just seeing the question

Comment: sorry,  all i want to know is if there is a way to print only letters from a text file instead of printing the whole text file

Answer (score 0):

Nathan, your couple1 variable contains all the characters in the file right? You could use something like:

```
couple2 = re.sub('[^a-z]+', '', couple1, flags=re.I)
print(couple2)
```

to remove all nonletter characters. Be sure to add:

```
import re
```

at the top of your programm in order to have access to the regular expression functions.